# Issue with FastLED and a simple counter

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, fastled

Okay, I'm having one baffling issue with this code.  The counter `pushCounterz` (named with a z only to rule out a conflicting variable) will start with the correct counter (1 or 0 or whichever) and one of a few things will happen when the button is pushed:

1. does nothing
2. correctly toggles the LED but the counter malfunctions in 1 of 2 ways

   1. counter will jump to -255 then on 2nd press resets to 1 and flips with each press between 1 and -255
   2. counter will not increment
   3. counter and/or LED will randomly increment w/o touching anything.

```cpp
    #include <FastLED.h>
    #define AnalogIn A0
    #define SwIn 2
    #define LED_Out 12
    #define NUM_LEDS 100
    int pushCounterz = 0;
    int buttonState;
    int lastButtonState;   // the previous reading from the input pin
    int ledPin = 13;
    int ledState = HIGH; 

    CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_Out, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      //pinMode(SwIn, INPUT);
      pinMode(LED_Out, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
      //Turn Off strip
      for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        leds[i] = CRGB ( 255, 0, 0 );
        FastLED.show();
      }
        digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
        Serial.begin(115200);
        Serial.println(pushCounterz);
        lastButtonState = digitalRead(SwIn); // Set the button state to the startup state 
    }

    void loop() {

      buttonState = digitalRead(SwIn);

   if (buttonState == LOW && buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    ledState = !ledState;
   }
   if (buttonState == LOW && buttonState != lastButtonState) {
        if (pushCounterz > 3) {
          Serial.println("Reset to 0: ");
          pushCounterz = 0;
        } else {
          pushCounterz = pushCounterz + 1;
          Serial.println("Incerment");
        }
        Serial.println(pushCounterz);
        switch (pushCounterz) {
          case 0:
            for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
              leds[i] = CRGB (255, 0, 0);
            }
            break;
          case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
              leds[i] = CRGB ( 0, 255, 0);
             }
             break;
          case 2:
            for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
               leds[i] = CRGB ( 0, 0, 255);
             }
            break;
          case 3:
           // theaterChaseRainbow(1,50);
            break;
          default:
           for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++) {
             leds[i] = CRGB ( 0, 0, 0);
           }
           break;
        }
      }
    FastLED.show();
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    lastButtonState = buttonState;
    }
```

However if I disable the switch code block, everything works flawlessly. I'm suspecting this is a bug in the FastLED library, however I wanted to ask here since I'm decently new to Arduino programming.

EDIT: Code above fixed one issue with the button.  I had changed the circuit to be HIGH and drop LOW, however didn't change the code. HOWEVER the state remains inconsistent, sometimes working and sometimes flipping between 1 and -255 (more-so the latter). Summary of change:

```
void setup() {
...
  lastButtonState = digitalRead(SwIn); // Set the button state to the startup state 
}

  */
  buttonState = digitalRead(SwIn);

  if (buttonState == LOW && buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    ledState = !ledState;
  }
  if (buttonState == LOW && buttonState != lastButtonState) {
```

EDIT: Serial output to show current craziness (with notes) after above edit:

```
0 <- initial startup correct
Incerment <- button push
1 <- correct increment
Incerment <- 2nd button push
-255 <- 1 + 1 does NOT equal -255
Incerment <- 3rd button push
1 <- ??? Assuming -255 +1 = 1?
Incerment
-255
```

Comment: Why is the code outside the function? Where is `loop()`? Why is `pinMode(SwIn, INPUT);` commented out? Do you even have a pulldown resistor like the button tutorial told you to?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the code to show the entire thing minus the disabled function(s) called in case 3:.  I had disabled the pinMode for a test but enabling it does not change anything.  Need a one of those fancy arduino molders to show the circuit diagram but it's hooked up like https://www.tinkercad.com/things/9IFe140QD43-button#/ minus the additional LED as I'm using the onboard one.  I was originally using the basic tutorial, but it was acting disconnected and constantly flipping states.

Comment: @gre_gor Here's an example of the serial output on startup:1
Incerment
2
Incerment
3
Every button press runs through a reset and then all increments stopping at 3

Comment: Why are you setting 101 LEDs? You only have 100.

Comment: There is actually 300 in the string, but just testing 100.  I'm baffled by the -255.  Not understanding the registers might be my downfall here and why 1+1 = -255 when the case statements are enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```c++
for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_LEDS; i++)
```

you are using the index 100, which is the 101th element of the array.

This is undefined behavior, which in your case causes trouble with `pushCounterz`.

Fix all your `for` loops that iterate through `leds`, by changing the `<=` operator with `<`.

```c++
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++)
```

Comment: Yup, that fixed it alright. Sort of a buffer overflow in the sense its writing over some area of memory containing my pushCounterz.  It explains the non-deterministic behavior of how adding/removing code blocks changed it's issues.  I *KNEW* it was going to be something generally dumb I wasn't seeing.